# What does Location means in R6RS of scheme?

Tags: scheme

At first, I thought that `set!` assignment in scheme is more like assignment `=` in python other than in c/c++.

in python:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> id(x)
15855960
>>> x = 2
>>> id(x)
15855936 # different from above!
```

the second assignment means rebind variable/name to another value instead of overwrite original value in memory location of `x`.

But c/c++ is the latter case:

```
int x = 1;
cout << &x << endl; // 0x7ffe3e6adba4
x = 2;
cout << &x << endl; // 0x7ffe3e6adba4  (the same memory location!)
```

But in `1.3` section of [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-4.html#node_sec_1.3):

> Scheme allows identifiers to stand for locations containing
>   values. These identifiers are called variables. In many
>   cases, specifically when the location’s value is never modified
>   after its creation, it is useful to think of the variable
>   as standing for the value directly.

And in `1.8 Assignment` section:

> Scheme variables bound by definitions or let or lambda
>   expressions are not actually bound directly to the objects
>   specified in the respective bindings, but to locations
>   containing these objects. The contents of these locations
>   can subsequently be modified destructively via assignment.

So it seems in scheme assignment `set!` is just like what c/c++ assignment `=`  does?

But then how to explain the following:

```
=> (define x 10)
=> x
10
=> (set! x "lonnnnnnnnnnnnng")
=> x
"lonnnnnnnnnnnnng"
```

At first `x` is a `location` to store an small integer. But later `set!` put a LONG string into that SMALL memory location? But the location have no enough memory space to do that I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the citations from the manual say the same thing: an identifier (e.g. a thing like `x` or `y`), is associated (“bound”) to a location (a memory cell, e.g. the cell at address 0x7ffe3e6adba4), that can hold different values (for instance an integer, a string etc.), and that the content of the location can be modified with a new value. That is:

```
Identifier -> Location -> Value
```

The value, depending from the combination language/compiler, can be either a direct value (or an “unboxed” values, as sometimes it is called, typically in case of values like integers or float), or a “boxed” value, that is a pointer to some memory area the contains the value (typically for complex values like cons cells, arrays, strings, etc.).

As I said, the key point is that the implementation is free to chose how to store values in location, for instance if use a uniform method of storing values according to their type, if optimize and allocate values with different strategies, etc. The only important thing is to strictly follow the specification of the language that requires the double map above. *The crucial point here is that in languages like Lisp pointers are (and should remain) “invisible” to the user (the programmer).*

Comment: Thanks very much for you answer!   So basically I was misunderstanding the term "value" which actually has two meaning: 1) direct value; 2) pointer/reference to real value. And it makes that scheme is indeed more like python although in python everything including (e.g. small integer ) is a reference/pointer under the hood.  Is that right?